# Mono/Unity3D disconnecting from a wcf duplex service after a while

Tags: wcf, mono, unity-game-engine

I have a client using unity3D which connects to a WCF duplex service. The client connects and receives data all the time, but after a random amount of minutes it just stops receiving data. The service stays stable and can be reconnected without any problem, also no error is thrown.

I have set up other test clients using .net 3.5 and the exact same code i use on mono and the client stays connected pretty much forever.

Does WCF in mono have known connectivity issues? How can i prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem, until I copy another version of System.ServiceModel.dll and System.Runtime.Serialization.dll in my Unity Asset (or plugin) folder. You can find these assemblies here : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/z05gp6zsqhshvpx/S-Wywb7NDh

(Running with Unity 4.2.2f1)

Have a good day !